# Calling Controller inside the querystring of another Controller MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

My application already has a common controller for spinner which in turn calls other controllers which form the part of a query string.

SpinnerController:

```
public ActionResult Index() { return View();}
```

Spinner View

```
<html>
    <body onload="JsHelpers.ShowSpinner('Page loading, please wait...'); window.location=JsHelpers.GetUrlParameter('page');"></body>
</html>
```

Now, My Home Controller:

```
public ActionResult Index() { /*my code goes here*/ return View()}
```

I've designed a master page which has links to call my HomeController via SpinnerController as I need to maintain the old flow.

For e.g: To Call HomeController,

```
@Url.Action("Index","Spinner", new  {page ="home"})
```

This gives me the url : `localhost/Spinner?page=home` and I identify the controller path via the QueryString after `page` in `_Layout.cshtml` as `Request.QueryString["page"]` and redirect it accordingly(in this case, HomeController)

Now, my problem arises when I need to send an input to the other controller which I want to call.

Consider, StudentController

```
Public ActionResult Index(int id) { /*my code goes here*/ return View()}
```

I need the url to be in the format `localhost/Spinner?page=Student?id=2`.
I used `@Url.Action` along with other methods which I have decent knowledge of and was unable to generate the url in the above format thereby being struck up with this for past few days.

So,

1. Could it be possible to generate the url in the format described above?
2. If yes, is it the right way to achieve things and is there a better way?

Any suggestion/advice/help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "localhost/Spinner?page=Student?id=2" should be "localhost/Spinner?page=Student&id=2"

Comment: What's the reason for all this? Why a masterpage if you have the _Layout.cshtml?

Comment: @greenhoorn Two masters and both were done by different organizations. One remained and the other is being removed and given to internal IT Team

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you add a new route and put it at top of route config at App_Start folder, as the following:

`routes.MapRoute(
            "spinner",
            "Spinner/Index/{page}/{parm1}/{parm2}",
            new { action = "Index", controller = "Spinner" }
        );`

Then you can get parameters in your action like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string page, string parm1, string parm2) {...}
```